# Finding All the Solutions of an Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follows:

> Find all solutions of $2^x = \frac{1}{x}.$

I graphed the equations $y = 2^x$ and $y = \frac{1}{x}$ to find the intersection point of $(0.641, 1.56)$. The two functions did not intersect anywhere else at all. Is there an algebraic way to solve the equation? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, the Lambert-W-function you can use also needs to be calculated numerically.

Comment: It makes me sad that you cannot write every function explicitly. This is one of those unfortunate functions. If you could find a clever way to rewrite it, maybe.

Comment: @peter Does an explicit form of the answer exist at all?

Comment: If you consider the Lambert-W-function to be explicit, yes. But there is no formula, like the formula to solve quadratics. This also arises for polynomials with degree larger than $4$, they also do not have a general formula to solve them by radicals. Only numerical methods can solve them in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use Lambert function, you may have a rather good approximation of $(x\, 2^x-1)$ using the simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant which , built for a function $f(x)$ at $x=a$, is given by
$$f(x)=\frac{f(a)+ \frac{2 f'(a)^2-f(a) f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a)} {1-\frac{f''(a)}{2 f'(a)}(x-a) }$$

Applied to your case, using  $a=1$. it would write as
$$\frac{1+A(x-1)}{1+B(x-1)}$$ with  $$A=\frac{4+3 \log ^2(2)+6 \log (2)}{2 (1+\log (2))}\qquad \text{and}\qquad B=-\frac{\log ^2(2)+2 \log (2)}{2 (1+\log (2))}$$ Solving for $0$, $x=1-\frac{1}{A} \approx 0.64727$ which is quite close to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following iteration to approximate the solution

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{x_n}}$$

Comment: Edit: evaluating it to a log iteration which gives $x_{n+1}=-\log(x_n)$, which clearly is undefined in the reals for $n\ge 2$ (and shows why $2^x=\frac 1x$ only has 1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f (x)=x\ln(2)+\ln (x) $$ for $x>0$.

$f $ is continuous at $(0,1] $.

$$f (1)>0$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f (x)=-\infty $$

$$f'(x)=\ln (2)+\frac {1}{x}>0$$

thus the equation $f (x)=0$ has only one root between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not amenable to an algebraic solution. Being transcendental only numerical iteration methods ( e.g., Newton-Raphson) will work. Apart from the correct root/solution you obtained by graphing there is one more root $x=-\infty$ where your sketched curves are asymptotically approaching the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
2^x&=\frac1x
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

There is a long-time known 
[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
that is used to make it easy to solve
equations like this.

\eqref{1} can be solved in terms of $\operatorname{W}$
as follows.

\begin{align} 
\exp(\ln(2^x))&=\frac1x
,\\
\exp(x\ln2)&=\frac1x
,\\
x\exp(x\ln2)&=1
,\\
x\ln2\exp(x\ln2)&=\ln2
,\\
\operatorname{W}(x\ln2\exp(x\ln2))
&=\operatorname{W}(\ln2);
,\\
x\ln2&=\operatorname{W}(\ln2)
,\\
x&=\frac{\operatorname{W}(\ln2)}{\ln2}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

And since the argument of 
$\operatorname{W}$ is $\ln2>0$,
we know that there is only one real root
in \eqref{2} 
and hence, in \eqref{1},

\begin{align} 
x&=\frac{\operatorname{W}(\ln2)}{\ln2}
\approx\frac{0.4444360910}{0.6931471806}
=0.6411857444
.
\end{align}

And here is just a one (python) way to get the numbers:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import lambertw as W
a=np.log(2)
print a
# 0.69314718056

print W(a)
# (0.444436091019+0j)

print W(a)/a
# (0.641185744505+0j)
```